# Global $user object isn't always "Fully Loaded"

Tags: 6, users

I have a Drupal 6 module that implements hook_user() to add a custom property on op='load';

```
mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  $account->external_id = mymodule_get_user_external_id($account->uid);
}
```

In modules, I access the global $user object. What I find is sometimes it has my ->external_id property, and sometimes it doesn't.

As a result, I end up having to check to see if my custom property is set, and if not, call user_load()

```
if(isset($GLOBALS['user']->external_id)) {
  $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
} else {
  $account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);
}
```

Yuck! Is this a known problem, or does it sound like I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you are doing it right as this is a known issue/behavior.  Check out http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/user/6 for a lot more information on it.  A link from there, http://drupal.org/node/57287, talks to your point directly (it is for D7 but is germaine to D6).

Answer (score 1):

With the user hooks, a general rule of thumb is that when the parameter in the API is specified as `$account`, don't expect it to be interchangeable with `$user`.  So, in your case, doing a `user_load()` to explicitly load the extra information is appropriate and needed.  [`hook_node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in Drupal 7 is another example that does this.  A similar thing happens with fieldable entities with some hooks, where not all of the fields are present in the argument passed into a hook.

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397735/hook-user-op-load-does-not-fire) on the main SO site that goes into this topic in more detail.  There is also a [related issue](http://drupal.org/node/361471) on drupal.org about it, too.